# Grafana Loki Distributed on Azure Kubernetes Service - Storage config

Tags: kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, grafana-loki, azure-storage-account

I want to run Grafana Loki (as distributed setup using helm) on AKS using Azure Storage Account as the backend and the setup for the storage is ambiguous, the

running "helm search repo grafana" lists the different versions of loki:

grafana/loki
grafana/loki-canary
grafana/loki-distributed
grafana/loki-simple-scalable
grafana/loki-stack

I want to use the distributed version because of the ability to scale each component - this is all good and fine, but the storage config is the main issue. As far as I can see it, there is no way to supply the key as a k8s secret. Tempo and Mirmir do support this in form of supplying it as a environment variable.

Managed Identities work fine, but I have one customer who needs it with the key :/

Thanks!

There are some open issues on GitHub talking about this and offerings some options but they don't work for the distributed chart. Has anyone successfully deployed it using Azure Storage Account and adding the key using an env var?

Comment: You might need to manually configure the storage settings to include Azure Storage and manage secrets. This often involves creating a K8s secret with your storage account keys and referencing this secret in your Loki configuration.
Create a Kubernetes secret with your Azure Storage account keys.
Configure the Loki Helm chart (grafana/loki-distributed) to use Azure Storage, adjusting the values.yaml file to include Azure blob storage details.
Ensure the configuration references the created k8s secret for storage keys. https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/setup/install/helm/configure-storage/

Comment: Hi Arko, thanks for reaching out. I tried exactly that, in every possible way with every loki helm chart there is - it does not work for me :(

Comment: What error do you get? Is it at least getting [deployed](https://i.imgur.com/VoL1nkN.png) using that custom values.yaml?

Comment: did you get this resolved? I was looking around and asked around. It seems that the Grafana Loki distributed version does not support supplying the Azure Storage Account key as a Kubernetes secret. However, some users have successfully deployed it using Managed Identities. One option to consider is using Tempo or Mirmir, which do support supplying the key as an environment variable.